# Regress function for Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, regression, multiple-regression

Using the regress function in excel and I am having trouble getting the output to post in the spot i want. Excel keeps creating a new workbook in which to place the results. What am I doing wrong? How do I target a space in my current workbook to paste the output of the regression?

```
Application.Run "ATPVBAEN.XLAM!Regress", Worksheets("statistics Database").Range("$C$7:$C$" & (7 + I - 1)), Worksheets("statistics Database").Range("$D$7:$F$" & (7 + I - 1)), False, True, , , True, , True, , Worksheets("statistical Output").Range("$A$1"), , False
```

Syntax is supposed to be:

```
Regress(inpyrng, inpxrng, constant, labels, confid, soutrng, residuals, 
sresiduals, rplots, lplots, routrng, nplots, poutrng)
```

I am adding the proper routrng and poutrng (So I thought. What am i doing wrong!)

Comment: You can open the .xlam file with the password `Wildebeest!!`. Then you will see the full parameters list and the whole logic behind the function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured out the answer:

First, for similar questions like mine, You can open the .xlam file with the password Wildebeest!!. Then you will see the full parameters list and the whole logic behind the function.

Second, the answer for this question was the **soutrng** parameter. This is the primairy reg-out.